# How to create a custom interface in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My team and I would like to be able to represent certain aspects of our project visually, but nothing currently out there will do the trick for us.

We'd like to build a visualization tool that could plug into Eclipse. For illustrative purposes, knowing how inCode from [Intooitus](http://www.intooitus.com/products/incode) was built would help us out a lot. I've attached a screenshot.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to build highly customizable visual components for Eclipse?

(A couple of the neat visualizations of inCode)

[image: Some visual tool examples]

Comment: I do not want to duplicate the product whatsoever. Did you read the question? I said "knowing how [they built it] would help us out a lot". IOW, I want to know what tools they used.

Comment: And I already own inCode.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad. I would recommend you to start by picking up some Eclipse plug-in development book.

You can try reading Eclipse documentation: [Plugging into Workbench](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench.htm) and an article on [editors](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors.htm?cp=2_0_13).

Note that you should create a new Plug-in project. That wizard allows you to use one of the templates when creating a new project.